# Python Reddit API PRAW: ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am making a python bot using the Reddit API the following is my code, the app secret and ID are being replaced for security but they are correct.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="id",
    client_secret="secret",
    username='username',
    password='password',
    user_agent="python:com.example.myredditapp:v1.2.3 (by u/MattCodes2003)",
)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('python')
hot_python = subreddit.hot(limit=5)

for submission in hot_python:
    print(submission)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I am quite confused regarding this error as tutorials and docs I have followed to the letter do not get this error thrown any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my authentication was wrong, hadn't put in the right password.